# How to set the alias variable so it can be used all the time

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, alias

I am a beginner and want to know how can i set alias variable in environment so that i can access it all the time instead of writing a long command.

So, i have VSCODE and it opens with this command.

```
/usr/share/code/code --no-sandbox --unity-launch %F
```

I did this ::

```
alias vscode = "usr/share/code/code --no-sandbox --unity-launch %F"
```

This works fine but does not work with new shell.

I tried doing this ::

```
export vscode
```

But did not work either.

Comment: You need to put bash shell aliases in the ~/.bashrc file. check this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/

Comment: Your example `alias vscode = arglebargle`  is not valid for bash, zsh, or ksh due to the extraneous whitespace. I'm guessing that you're using one of those shells or another POSIX shell. Note that command aliases are not variables in any of those shells. Aliases and variables have distinct namespaces. You should always copy/paste the literal text from your terminal window. It should include the command you typed and the error text you saw.